# Bootstrap разметка. xs, md

Tags: css, bootstrap

Не могу понять, как в бутстрапе расположить 6 элементов.
Хочу чтобы на мобильных они были в 3 ряда, а на декстопах в 2.

Если делаю так:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">...</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">...</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">...</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">...</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">...</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">...</div>
</div>
```

То, на декстопах 4 элемент из-за того, что там float left, подтягивается в притык к 3му. 
Как решается в бустрапе этот вопрос?

[image: скрин]

Comment: Приведите вашу верстку с учетом `<div class="row">`, пожалуйста. И по возможности - приложите скриншот, где у вас едет верстка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Классы `lg`и `xs` забыли + если блоки все разной высоты, то рекомендую использовать [`clearfix`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">...</div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">...</div>

 <!--Clearfix to Blockes in a Row -->
 <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
 <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">...</div>

 <!--Clearfix to Blockes in a Row -->
 <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
 <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">...</div>

 <!--Clearfix to Blockes in a Row -->
 <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
 <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">...</div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">...</div>
</div>
```

И по возможности используйте `container-fluid`.

Comment: 1) `col-xs-4` работает и на широком экране, пока не включится `col-md-6`, поэтому достаточно `col-md-6 col-xs-4`; 2) вместо `<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div><div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>` лучше `<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block"></div>`; 3) ряду [положено лежать в контейнере](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro), иначе он создаёт горизонтальную прокрутку на странице; 4) три ряда на мобиле - это две колонки, т.е. нужно всё-таки `col-xs-6 col-md-4` и по другому распределить блоки с `clearfix`.